# SQL Server stored procedure - Table to XML object

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I need to write a stored procedure that can create the following output from values from a SQL Server table:

```
<object>
  <ValueList>
    <Value value="1" text="Name" enabled="1" alias="Alias" />
    <Value value="2" text="Name" enabled="1" alias="Alias" />
    <Value value="3" ....
    ...
    ...
  </ValueList>
</object>
```

I have tried to convert my table into XML using this procedure:

```
select TXT as [text]
from lit_geography
for XML raw ('value'), root('object')
```

Then I get the following

```
<object>
  <value text="Midler tidig havn" />
  <value text="Færgehavnsvej" />
  <value text="Sydhavnsvej" />
  <value text="Ø-Pladsen" />
  <value text="Havnepladsen" />
</object>
```

TODO:

- I am missing the parent node Valuelist
- I need to append the following:

  ```
  value="1", value="2" etc etc counting up for each value  
  enabled="1"
  alias=""
  ```

Comment: What is the structure and content of the SQL table(s) you are trying to pull the data from?

Answer (score 3):

For the incremental value, you can use **Row_Number()**

**Example**

```
Select (
         Select [value]   = row_number() over (Order by (select null))
               ,[text]    = txt
               ,[enabled] = 1
               ,[alias]   = 'Alias'
          From  lit_geography
          For XML Raw('Value'),type
        )
 For XML Path('ValueList'),Root('object')
```

**Returns**

```
<object>
  <ValueList>
    <Value value="1" text="Midler tidig havn" enabled="1" alias="Alias" />
    <Value value="2" text="Færgehavnsvej" enabled="1" alias="Alias" />
    <Value value="3" text="Sydhavnsvej" enabled="1" alias="Alias" />
    <Value value="4" text="Ø-Pladsen" enabled="1" alias="Alias" />
    <Value value="5" text="Havnepladsen" enabled="1" alias="Alias" />
  </ValueList>
</object>
```

> **EDIT - Requested UPDATE**

```
 Update lit_formfield set [Values] = (
 Select (
         Select [value]   = row_number() over (Order by (select null))
               ,[text]    = txt
               ,[enabled] = 1
               ,[alias]   = 'Alias'
          From  lit_geography
          For XML Raw('Value'),type
        )
 For XML Path('ValueList'),Root('object')
 )
 Where Label = 'listbox'
```

Comment: Works 100% John - thank you so much - Last thing to do is add the above object to a variable and update it into a table again .. is that the right way around to it ?

Comment: @JohnnyKureJakobsen Happy to help.   Not sure I understand your last comment.  You can store the XML to a variable and then update a table or just update the table... not clear on your structure

Comment: I got a table called lit_formfield(Label, Values) need to update values field in the row with the above object , where Label is equal “listbox”

Comment: @JohnnyKureJakobsen See Update